# Emacs + Evil: non incremental search and persistent highlighting?

Tags: vim, emacs, evil-mode

I'm trying Emacs+Evil after almost two decades as a Vim user. I'm moving most of my Vim configuration to Evil but one thing that I'm having a lot of problems is to set the search and highlighting like the one I use with Vim. What I'm trying to get is to have non-incremental search and the highlights to remain until I clear them manually or make another search.

I've set these settings on my config file:

```
;; keep the search highlights
(setq lazy-highlight-cleanup nil)
(setq lazy-highlight-max-at-a-time nil)
(setq lazy-highlight-initial-delay 0)
```

Using the `/` key to search with Evil does the incremental thing and also the highlights are removed as soon as I press any other movement key (like `j` key but with `C-s` (emacs internal i-search) the highlights remain. With `C-s RET` (non incremental search) the highlights doesn't remain.

Comment: congrats for the jump ! I didn't find an option. At least you could remap the `/` key to the builtin non-incremental search. See `C-h k <your key>` to see the function's name. So something like `(define-key evil-normal-state-map "/" 'search-forward)` ?

Comment: it would be nice seeing you edit this doc if you feel it is too sparse: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil

Comment: @Ehvince thanks for the tip, I did it. I'll check Evil's source to see if there is a way to have what I want. I'm writing an article about the settings I'm changing and I'll publish it soon, I'll check that wiki too to see if I can add something useful.

Comment: Cool, come post the link here !

Comment: Made an extension, check my comment on the solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found a working solution for the highlighting:

```lisp
(defun highlight-remove-all ()
  (interactive)
  (hi-lock-mode -1)
  (hi-lock-mode 1))

(defun search-highlight-persist ()
  (highlight-regexp (car-safe (if isearch-regexp
                                  regexp-search-ring
                                search-ring)) (facep 'hi-yellow)))

(defadvice isearch-exit (after isearch-hl-persist activate)
  (highlight-remove-all)
  (search-highlight-persist))

(defadvice evil-search-incrementally (after evil-search-hl-persist activate)
  (highlight-remove-all)
  (search-highlight-persist))
```

This will highlight all searches done with isearch or Evil search. The highlight will remain until you make another one or call `highlight-remove-all`. I've mapped it to `leader SPC` with:

```lisp
(evil-leader/set-key "SPC" 'highlight-remove-all)
```

PS: I made a package, it's already on melpa with the name "evil-search-highlight-persist" and: https://github.com/juanjux/evil-search-highlight-persist

Answer (score 3):

To make '/' search work like it does in vim (highlight persists until you search again), put this before you `(require 'evil)`:

```
(setq evil-search-module 'evil-search)
```

Comment: If I set it up this way, some keys do not work properly i. e. search again (n key) was trying to invoke isearch. For me the solution was to do: `(evil-select-search-module 'evil-search-module 'evil-search)` after `(evil-mode 1)` .

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but it came up as the first hit on Google, and I just wanted to add...

You can disable incremental searching altogether with:

```
(setq evil-ex-search-incremental nil)
```